# Best way to remove the last blank space from words read using sstream?

Tags: c++, stringstream

So, my code is supposed to scramble words of a sentence without altering the order they appear on the input. The code works fine, but at the end of the output there's a blank space which leads to a presentation error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string line;
    while(getline(cin,line)){
        stringstream ss(line);
        string word;
        while(ss>>word){
            string sWord;
            for(int i=word.length()-1;i>=0;i--) {
                sWord+=word.at(i);
            } 
            cout << sWord << " ";
        } 
    cout << endl;
    }
}
```

That is caused by the `cout << sWord << " ";` line which prints a blank space regardless of the position of the word. I've attempted to rewrite that part of the code to:

```
cout << sWord;
if(ss>>word) cout << " "; // if there is a following word, print the space; else don't
```

But since I'm writing `ss>>word` again, when the the next iteration begins, it begins on the 3rd word(or 5th, 7th,etc.) skipping what I do not intend to.

Is there a simple way of achieving this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `bool` to test whether you're displaying the *first* word or not, like:

```
bool is_first = true; // bool flag to test whether first word or not 
while(ss>>word){
        string sWord;
        for(int i=word.length()-1;i>=0;i--) {
            sWord+=word.at(i);
        }
        if(is_first){ // first word
            cout << sWord;
            is_first = false;
        }
        else{ // not first word
            cout << " " << sWord;
        }
}
```

In this way, you effectively print `" " << sWord;` at each iteration, except on the first iteration, where you don't output the space.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the tip! I wrote a bit differently but it did the trick. Instead of using `else` I did `is_first = false; continue;`. Never thought of using a boolean variable for that. Guess I lack the experience.

Comment: @GabrielRebello exactly, continue is equally good. The generated code is probably exactly the same.

Comment: @GabrielRebello Related: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4066.htm

Answer (score 0):

I pitch something more along the lines of this:

```
while(getline(cin,line))
{
    stringstream ss(line);
    string word;
    if (ss>>word)
    {
        string sWord;
        for(int i=word.length()-1;i>=0;i--) 
        {
            sWord=word.at(i);
        } 
        cout << sWord;
        while(ss>>word)
        {
            for(int i=word.length()-1;i>=0;i--) 
            {
                sWord+=word.at(i);
            } 
            cout << " " << sWord;
        } 
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

One extra if, but it only goes once. Code repeated, but it's a pretty small block.

Answer (score 0):

Consider appending the space in front of the actual word:

```
int main () {
    string line;
    while(getline (cin, line)) {
        stringstream ss (line);
        string word;
        bool first = true;
        while(ss >> word) {
            if(first) {
                first = false; //skip the space for the first word
            } else cout << " ";
            string sWord;
            for(int i = word.length () - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                sWord += word.at (i);
            }
            cout << sWord;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```